# Calculate/approach individual face probabilities of 10-faced dice, based on summed 2-roll dice experiment

Tags: r, least-squares, algebra, dice

I have a biochemistry problem , that can be simplified as a two-roll dice experiment (I think...).

Assume there is an uneven dice with 10 faces, i.e. individual face probabilities are not 1/10. We want to know these probabilities.

The given dataset that we have, however, is a histogram of summed faces of rolling the (same) dice twice. So, the range of the observed bins is 2-20 (2 = 1+1; 3 = 1+2, 2+1, 4 = 2+2, 1+3, 3+1; etc.).

The probabilities of summed faces are the product of the individual probabilities (s: observed probabilities of summed faces; p: probabilities of individual faces) and can be written as follows:

```
s2 ~ p1^2
s3 ~ 2*p1*p2
s4 ~ 2*p1*p3 + p2^2
s5 ~ 2*p1*p4 + 2*p2*p3
s6 ~ 2*p1*p5 + 2*p2*p4 + p3^2
s7 ~ 2*p1*p6 + 2*p2*p5 + 2*p3*p4
s8 ~ 2*p1*p7 + 2*p2*p6 + 2*p3*p5 + p4^2
s9 ~ 2*p1*p8 + 2*p2*p7 + 2*p3*p6 + 2*p4*p5
s10 ~ 2*p1*p9 + 2*p2*p8 + 2*p3*p7 + 2*p4*p6 + p5^2
s11 ~ 2*p1*p10 + 2*p2*p9 + 2*p3*p8 + 2*p4*p7 + 2*p5*p6
s12 ~ 2*p2*p10 + 2*p3*p9 + 2*p4*p8 + 2*p5*p7 + p6^2
s13 ~ 2*p3*p10 + 2*p4*p9 + 2*p5*p8 + 2*p6*p7
s14 ~ 2*p4*p10 + 2*p5*p9 + 2*p6*p8 + p7^2
s15 ~ 2*p5*p10 + 2*p6*p9 + 2*p7*p8
s16 ~ 2*p6*p10 + 2*p7*p9 + p8^2
s17 ~ 2*p7*p10 + 2*p8*p9
s18 ~ 2*p8*p10 + p9^2
s19 ~ 2*p9*p10
s20 ~ p10^2
```

In this case there are 20-1=19 known variables, and 10 unknowns, so the system is over-determined. It is also easy to solve by hand using algebra. As far as I can remember: quadratic terms will result in 2 possible solutions per individual face. Probabilities are always positive, so practically there should be one solution. Right?

Is there a way to solve this system in R? I am familiar with linear inverse problems in R, but I don't know how to approach this (quadratic?) system in R.

Here is some code to simulate the problem:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

dice <- data.frame(face = 1:10)

### functions
split_dice_faces <- function(summed_face){
  face_face <- strsplit(x = as.character(summed_face),split = "[/_\\|]")[[1]]
  names(face_face) <- c("face1","face2")
  as.numeric(face_face)
}

sum_dice_faces <- function(face_face){
  sapply(face_face, function(face_face_i){
    face1 <- split_dice_faces(face_face_i)[1]
    face2 <- split_dice_faces(face_face_i)[2]
    sum(c(face1[1], face2[1]))
  })
}

simulate_2_rolls <- function(dice_pool){
  dice_perm <- data.frame(permutations(n = dim(dice_pool)[1], r = 2, v = as.character(dice_pool$face), repeats.allowed = T ))
  dice_perm$face_face <- paste(dice_perm[[1]],"|",dice_perm[[2]], sep = "")
  dice_perm$prob <- dice_pool$prob[match(dice_perm[[1]], dice_pool$face)]*dice_pool$prob[match(dice_perm[[2]], dice_pool$face)]
  
  dice_perm$summed_face <- sum_dice_faces(dice_perm$face_face)
   
  
  dice_perm <- dice_perm %>% arrange(summed_face) %>% select(one_of(c("face_face", "summed_face","prob")))
  dice_perm
  
}

summarise_2_rolls_experiment <- function(simulate_2_rolls_df){
  simulate_2_rolls_df %>% group_by(summed_face) %>% summarise(prob = sum(prob))
}
  
from_face_probs_to_summed_observations <- function(face_probs){
  face_probs %>% 
    data.frame(face = dice$face, prob = .) %>%
    simulate_2_rolls()  %>% 
    summarise_2_rolls_experiment() %>% 
    pull(prob)
}

generate_formulas <- function() {
  
  output <- 
    dice_sum_probs %>% group_by(summed_face) %>% group_split() %>%
    sapply(function(i){
      
      left_hand <- paste("s",i$summed_face[1],sep="")
      
      right_hand <-
        sapply(strsplit(i$face_face, "\\|") , function(row){
          row_i <- as.numeric(row)
          row_i <- row_i[order(row_i)]
          row_i <- paste("p",row_i,sep = "")
          if(row_i[1] == row_i[2]){
            paste(row_i[1],"^2",sep="")
          } else {
            paste(row_i,collapse="*")
          }
        })
      
      
      right_hand <-
        paste(sapply(unique(right_hand), function(right_hand_i){
          fact <- sum(right_hand == right_hand_i)
          if(fact > 1){fact <- paste(fact,"*",sep = "")} else {fact <- ""}
          paste(fact,right_hand_i,sep = "")
        }), collapse = " + ")
      
      paste(left_hand, "~", right_hand)
      
    })
  
  return(output)
  
}
```

to simulate a dataset:

```
### random individual probabilites
dice_probs <- data.frame(face = dice$face, 
                         prob = runif(n = dim(dice)[1]) %>% (function(x){x / sum(x)}))
dice_probs

### simulate infinite amount of trials, observations expressed as probabilities
dice_sum_probs <- simulate_2_rolls(dice_probs)
dice_sum_probs

### sum experiment outcomes with the same sum
dice_sum_probs_summary <- dice_sum_probs %>% group_by(summed_face) %>% summarise(prob = sum(prob))

### plot, this is the given dataset
with(data = dice_sum_probs_summary, barplot(prob, names.arg = summed_face))

### how to calculate / approach p1, p2, ..., p10?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we create a multiplication table of the probabilities, `outer(p, p)` and then sum those over constant values of `outer(1:10, 1:10, "+")` using `tapply` we get the following nonlinear regression problem:

```
nls(prob ~ tapply(outer(p, p), outer(1:10, 1:10, `+`), sum), 
  dice_sum_probs_summary, algorithm = "port",
  start = list(p = sqrt(dice_sum_probs_summary$prob[seq(1, 19, 2)])),
  lower = numeric(10), upper = rep(1, 10))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: prob ~ tapply(outer(p, p), outer(1:10, 1:10, `+`), sum)
   data: dice_sum_probs_summary
     p1      p2      p3      p4      p5      p6      p7      p8      p9     p10 
0.06514 0.04980 0.14439 0.06971 0.06234 0.19320 0.09491 0.01237 0.11936 0.18878 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.33e-30
```

which is consistent with

```
> dice_probs
   face       prob
1     1 0.06513537
2     2 0.04980455
3     3 0.14438749
4     4 0.06971313
5     5 0.06234477
6     6 0.19319613
7     7 0.09491289
8     8 0.01236557
9     9 0.11936244
10   10 0.18877766
```

We can alternately express it as follows where X is a matrix of zeros and ones having dimension 19 x 100 such that each row corresponds to a possible outcome of rolling the two dice (i.e. 2:20) and each column corresponds to a pair of indexes from 1:10 and 1:10.  An entry equals one if the column pair sums to the sum of the two faces represented by its row and zero otherwise.

```
g <- c(outer(1:10, 1:10, `+`))
X <- + outer(2:20, g, `==`)
nls(prob ~ X %*% kronecker(p, p), dice_sum_probs_summary, alg = "port",
  start = list(p = sqrt(dice_sum_probs_summary$prob[seq(1, 19, 2)])),
  lower = numeric(10), upper = rep(1, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm! Would there be a preference for the first or second approach? Do they differ under the hood or are they essentially the same?

My real problem is somewhat more complicated with measuring error and missing data. But your solution seems to be quite robust, based on the simulated datasets.

Comment: The two right hand sides represent the same function of p so from that viewpoint they are the same and they both converge in the same number of iterations.  The first avoids forming a large matrix X but that matrix might have some use in other areas of the problem.